# jQuery attribute selector not working inside $.ajax call (IE6, IE7)

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer

I'm trying to select some links in my content after an AJAX call, but it doesn't seem to be working in IE6 and IE7 (haven't tested 8 or 9). The links are supposed to be overridden when clicked, and an alert is supposed to triggered instead. However, IE still tries to go to the address. It works fine in Chrome and Firefox.

Here's the main HTML document

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>Cavern Sounds - Music production services</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<a href="someplace.html">someplace 1</a>
<div id="content"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$.ajax({
  url: "content.html",
  success: 
    function(html){
      $("#content").html(html);
      $('a[href="someplace.html"]').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        alert("hello world");});
    }
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

and here's "content.html", the snippet that's being retrieved by the AJAX call

```
<a href="someplace.html">someplace 2</a>
```

An interesting thing to note is that IE still overrides the first link (the one that isn't being retrieved by the AJAX call). It's just the link inside the content retrieved by the AJAX call that isn't being overridden.

Any suggestions are appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: As an aside, you should put your last `script` tag *inside* of the body or head.

Comment: Ah thanks, yeah I just messed up when making the example.

Comment: You might try using a selector for the href for contains "someplace.html" rather than equals like this: `$('a[href*="someplace.html"]')` or this (ends with): `$('a[href$="someplace.html"]')`

Comment: @jfriend00 Yes, this turned out to be the case. However, the = selector still works for the first link, but the AJAX link requires the *= selector to work. Can anyone provide a solution that allows for the use of the = selector for the AJAX query? Or perhaps an explanation as to why it can't be used in this case?

Comment: I just know that if you fetch the href value from the link with Javascript, it will return a fully qualified URL regardless of what was originally in the source, so perhaps that's why you can't match just the filename with = even if that's what was originally in the page.  Maybe IE works differently on links that were in the original page vs. links added later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this which is using live to bind the events

```
$(function(){

$('a[href*="someplace.html"]').live('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        alert("hello world");
});

$.ajax({
  url: "content.html",
  success: 
    function(html){
      $("#content").html(html);
   }
});

});
```

Comment: Hmm, just tried it. Still doesn't seem to be working in IE6 and 7 though... =/

Comment: Can you please alert the html content in the ajax call success handler and see what is the href for the anchor tags in it? I think the selector is not matching so the event is not firing.

Comment: Works! Although, turns out my original code works as soon as I change the selector to *= instead of =. The strange thing is, I alerted the content from the AJAX request, and the URL was still just "someplace.html", so I don't know why = doesn't work... I'd rather use = than *= since it's more specific. Could this be a bug in jQuery?

Comment: It is not a bug. "=" looks for exact match where as "*=" looks for contains in the attribute passed. I am glad it worked thanks.

Comment: Yes, but in this case, didn't I want to look for an exact match?

Comment: You can check for an exact match but I guess in the ajax call response the anchor's href is not the same as we are expecting, may be case mismatch. But as along as it is able to find with "*=" selector it should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>Cavern Sounds - Music production services</title>
<script type="text/javascript" 

src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
$.ajax({
  url: "content.html",
  success: 
    function(html){
      $("body").html(html);
      $('a[href*="someplace.html"]').live("click",(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        alert("hello world");}));
alert($('a[href*="someplace.html"]').size());
    }

});
</script>
```

more details here [Error in jquery attribute selector and IE6-7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3046557/error-in-jquery-attribute-selector-and-ie6-7)

Comment: +1 I didn't even see the selector thing...too focused on the binding.

Answer (score 0):

Try using .live() instead of .click() or even better use .delegate().

The link you're trying to bind has been introduced later and may not be available before the .click() binding.

Here's a JSfiddle for this but now it looks like maybe it was a selector issue...
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kasdega/jpRTP/)

Comment: Yes, I think it was some sort of AJAX (returned content) selector issue, but I still don't understand why = works for the first link and not the second one. I think there is some sort of bug here...