# $('input[type="submit"]') does not work on IE 6, how to make it aware of the element?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, internet-explorer-6

I am using jQuery to select and pop an alert when user click button. 
The below code works on 'standard' browsers (Chrome, Firefox, etc), but IE 6 fails.

```
$('input[type="submit"]').click(function(event) {event.preventDefault();});
$('input[type="submit"]').click(function() {alert('hi')});
```

Looks like jQuery selector of such input won't work in IE 6. How can I make it compatible for IE 6 as well?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3046557/error-in-jquery-attribute-selector-and-ie6-7

Comment: Do you think there are still IE6 users?

Comment: @Drupalizer Yes, unfortunately, this site has a large number (40% ~ 50%) of IE 6 audience due to its company policy. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can assign your buttons a class and then reference with that.

```
<input type="submit" class="runthis" />

$(".runthis").click(function() { });
```

EDIT: this code works for me in IE6:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {

            $("input[type='submit']").click(function() {

                alert("HI");
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <input type="submit" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is true, but you're just avoiding the question.

Comment: The question states "how to make IE6 aware".  This makes IE6 aware.  It's a workaround, but there's no way to make IE6 natively support such a selector.  I figured it was a better answer than simply saying "You can't".

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3046557/error-in-jquery-attribute-selector-and-ie6-7

Comment: @KevinBoucher followed the link, I tried $('input[type="SUBMIT"]'), doesn't work either.

Comment: @Darrrrrren  I tried your suggession. I add an id to the input , then use $('#the-form-id')   . same, doesn't work.

Comment: @gilzero I have updated my answer - which version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: Well, it works for me in IE6 with jQuery 1.4.4.  Not sure what issue you could be having, sorry!

Comment: Thanks, @Darrrrrren it works now, replaced the double quote with single quote.    $('input[type="SUBMIT"]')   >>>>>   $('input[type='SUBMIT']')