# jquery color swap not working in IE

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer

I have a simple jQuery script to replace the bgcolors values of the rows of a large table. However It will not work in IE 6 - 9.

Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
$(document).ready(function() {

    // Swap all blue tr bg colors to red and grey shades 

    $('tr[bgcolor=#9BB9FB]').attr('bgcolor','#E6B8B7');
    $('tr[bgcolor=#B9CBFD]').attr('bgcolor','#F2DCDB');
    $('tr[bgcolor=#B6D3FC]').attr('bgcolor','#F2DCDB');
    $('tr[bgcolor=#015B91]').attr('bgcolor','#E6B8B7');
    $('tr[bgcolor=#8EBCFD]').attr('bgcolor','#B5B5B5');
    $('tr[bgcolor=#015B91 ]').attr('bgcolor','#e6b8b7');

});
</script>
```

Comment: Do you have to use the `bgcolor` attribute? Do you have the same issue if you change `.attr` to `.prop`?

Comment: There are a few suggestions in this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3046557/error-in-jquery-attribute-selector-and-ie6-7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below code :

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
        $(document).ready(function() {

        // Swapp All Blue tr bg colros to red and grey shades 

        $('tr[bgcolor=#9BB9FB]').css("background-color",'#E6B8B7');
        $('tr[bgcolor=#B9CBFD]').css("background-color",'#F2DCDB');
        $('tr[bgcolor=#B6D3FC]').css("background-color",'#F2DCDB');
        $('tr[bgcolor=#015B91]').css("background-color",'#E6B8B7');
        $('tr[bgcolor=#8EBCFD]').css("background-color",'#B5B5B5');
        $('tr[bgcolor=#015B91 ]').css("background-color",'#e6b8b7');

     });
     </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried something like this? Or using classing rather then setting the attr?

var p = $("tr[bgcolor=#9BB9FB]").css("background-color", "yellow");
      p.css("background-color", "#E6B8B7");

Comment: Thankyou  people for you help found a reply from hexbot on a previous question of mine the solution is to add double quotes "" around the hex value I was trying to select like so :  $('tr[bgcolor=#"015B91" ]').attr('bgcolor','#e6b8b7');