# jQuery 1.7.2 and IE7 on() doesn't seem to fire for selects

Tags: internet-explorer-7, jquery

I have a table of rows where are dynamically added, but for some reason the `on()` event doesn't seem to fire when I change the value of a select.

For simplicity, I wrote the following [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CVNky/1/).  This is a VERY simplistic example of what I am doing.  I do have to note that I was unable to verify if the jsFiddle failed the same way in IE7 because jsFiddle does not seem to work in IE7 at all.

The basics of my code are this...

First, the page loads with 1 or more of these rows, which represent a complex "subform" to be posted to Spring MVC.  The subform has a group of 5 `SELECT` tags that have an event handler attached at the top `TABLE` as such:

```
$('#parentTable').on('change', 'div.additional div[class^="additional"] select', function() {
    // ...enable/disable siblings according to value
}
```

At the bottom of the table is an **Add** button.  When the user clicks it, I take the last visible row, clone it, use regex to *fix* the index on the name/id, and set all the fields blank and disables except one field, which is used to do a lookup.  This all has the appearance of working.

The user enters a value in the lookup field, clicks **Lookup**, which performs an AJAX call, filling in the subform then calling the change on the selects to set their default state like so:

```
$subTable.find(':input:not(:button)').change();
```

This fires the above `on()` as expected.  However, if I physically click on the resulting `SELECT`s and change their values the `on()` event handler is not called.

I have verified that the resulting cloned table row looks/smells/feels correct, at least from using IE8's Developer Tools (I have IE8 in IE7 compatibility mode for testing, because IE7 has VERY limited testing and the problem seems to be present there too).  When I run this in Chrome it works perfectly fine, however I am aware the clone is technically working differently.

Any help would be appreciated.

**Update**

I tried swapping the selector to drop the class attr as suggested below:

```
$('#parentTable').on('change', 'div.additional div select', function() {
    // ...enable/disable siblings according to value
}
```

And I tried all caps like the referenced post:

```
$('#parentTable').on('change', 'div.additional div[class^="ADDITIONAL"] select', function() {
    // ...enable/disable siblings according to value
}
```

The first worked the same way, the second did nothing at all (disabled all `on()` change handling).

Will continue to play with this until I get it working.  There has to be something simple going wrong here.

**Update 2**

```
I tried adding a class to all the `SELECT`s, and added the following two:
$('select.addedClass').on('change', function() {
    alert("Select change:" + $(this).val());
});
$('#parentTable').on('change', 'select.addedClass', function() {
    alert("Select change 2:" + $(this).val());
});
```

Here is the process I performed:

1. Reloaded page, both alerts fire for the single row there
2. Added a row
3. Performed AJAX lookup, which calls `$addedTable.find(':input:not(:button)').change();` as described above, both events fire
4. Change the value of one of the selects, neither alert fires.

I would expect the first to fail, since the event listener is connected directly to the `SELECT` and not a higher level parent, but the second one fails the same way.  So, in the Developer Tools, I tried to run the following:

```
$('#order.itemList1.additionalLine1').change()
```

Which is the ID of one of the selects I added, and still nothing fired.  It's as if the event handler is ignoring all added `SELECT`s.

To make sure the select was working on the `on()`, I did this in the console after I added the new row:

```
$('#parentTable').find('div.additional div[class^="additional"] select').each(function() {
    alert($(this).attr('name') + '(' + $(this).prop('id') + ')' + ' : ' + $(this).val());
});
```

**Update 3**

I ended up putting in a horrible hack that, for IE7 only, drops and re-adds the change handler directly on the `SELECT`s.  It's ugly, but I have to support IE7, so...

I am leaving this open to see if anyone has a better solution, or might know why it's not working.

Answer (score 2):

The problem isn't the `change` event, or the delegation on `select` elements.

It's the attribute selector:

```
div[class^="additional"]
```

IE7 and below don't do attribute selectors.

I've done a bit of searching and a few people seem to think [this can be solved using case-specific syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3046557/error-in-jquery-attribute-selector-and-ie6-7).

Comment: That's true if you're talking about plain CSS, but the OP isn't asking about CSS, he's asking about jQuery, and jQuery allows complex selectors in all supported browsers, including IE7.

Comment: @Spudley - yes, you're right to an extent. It's quite a common problem though (lots of results in a search), so jQuery (1.7.2) may not have solved all of the issues.

Comment: I should point out that the first row works fine, as does the call using `.change()` after I add a new row.  It's just after that things seem to not work.

Comment: Updated original post.